# Angular2 force/hard reload of browser cached scripts?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, angular2-routing, versioning

I know that there are a lot of posts about that in web, but none of them satisfied me.
Most of people recommends appending a verizon number to each script/css file. But this sound like a lot of job to me (project is qute bit), maybe there is some way to version only output files, some CLI command I dont know?

My solution was based of simple pinging to API for new version number, when > than stored then reload the page. And here is a tricky part - even `location.reload(true)` does not refresh the cached angular stuff. Manually CTRL+SHIFT+R does this job nicely. This would be good enough for me if the programmaticly hard reload would work.

I also tried a `this.compiler.clearCache();` but also with no effect.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5):

The `@angular/cli` does the cache busting for you. It appends the hash to script/css file names if you run the `ng build` with the `--prod` flag.

[image: ng build]

Comment: Thx! This would be perfect, but I m currently facing a problem "JavaScript heap out of memory" whe try build with --prod flag. I will try some workaround to increase the max RAM amount for build. Or maybe U know some?

Comment: Found a solution for max heap exception. Seems like I have to use a long command since we are using VSTS for auto deployment thus I cant just edit ng files.
'node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod '
Indeed I see a guid appended to files. Hope this will help me. Thx again!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: If you are using the angular-cli, the @Tomasz's answer is probably better than the methods listed below.

Ideally you would use a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or a task runner like [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) to automatically 'fingerprint' your files (ie, append a unique identifier to the file name based on it's contents).

But if that is not an option, a simple hack would be to :

1. set the caching headers on your HTML to avoid caching on the browser
2. Append a random query parameter to your script tag URLs in your HTML which you can change each time you want a new version.

---

```
<script src='/js/some.js?v=1.1.3'></script>
```

Changing the random query parameter (`v` in the example) will ensure the browser makes a fresh request as the URL is different than the cached (older) version